# Heatmap based on DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

The Dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3],"B":[4,5,6]})
print(df)

   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

transformed into a heatmap using

```
fig = px.density_heatmap(df)
fig.show()
```

results in

[image]

What I actually want, is the index (0,1,3) on the x-axis, column names (A,B) on the y axis and the actual cell values represented by colors, as a third dimension. How can I get that representation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use [`px.imshow`](https://plotly.com/python/imshow/):

```
px.imshow(df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might use [`seaborn.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) for this task following way

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3],"B":[4,5,6]})
sns.heatmap(df).get_figure().savefig('heatmap.png')
```

creates file `heatmap.png`
[image: heatmap]